# Our calculators are lazy

Tags: terminology, calculator

When you think about it, our calculators basically do nothing at all except change the syntax of the number that you enter. We enter a number with multiplication, division and other symbols in it and the calculator gives back the same number in a differebt format.

Why do we call them calculators if they don't actually calculate anything?

Comment: Who uses calculators these days?

Comment: Please tell me what $7$ times $11$ times $13$ is NOW! Did you have to do any work?

Comment: According to what definition of "calculate" do calculators not calculate anything?

Comment: @Rob Arthan It's just (7*11*13)

Comment: Your deep thought is probably that there are as many ways as you want to represent a given quantity, but switching from one to another is _a priori_ far from being as trivial as you seem to state.

Comment: @DougM: apparently calculators are alive and well: see  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883798/complex-solutions-of-z-1-z1-z2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I have had an HP 15C since about 1982 and it is just wonderful. It takes short programs, I can put in a custom function and draw a graph on actual graph paper. I also like dogs, and they like me. Usually.

Comment: When you ask your calculator to calculate $5+3$ it returns $8$.  That's not just the same number in a different format, you start with two numbers and end up with one, their sum *computed* using logic gates in the central processing unit of the calculator.  So indeed calculators really do calculate.

Comment: @Me2:  $7*11*13$ as processed by your calculator is not $7*11*13$: it's $7*11*13$ put into a normal form $1001$ so that it can be compared with other things like $4*250+1$ or $MI$. To discount calculation as just a "change of syntax" is to disparage thousands of years of human achievement.

Comment: @WillJagy the HP12-C is a legend of personal electronics.  In continuous production for 45 years, still with the original design.

Comment: I'm not upvoting this, but I don't really think it deserves to be closed. It's an interesting thought and question to have, and I think it's worth answering (even if the OP also should have thought about their own question a little more, perhaps). I would perhaps encourage a different title, though . . .

Comment: @DougM I'm guessing it is similar to the 15C. I put in the bit about graphs because so many students on MSE seem never to have drawn a graph of any kind on paper. I do use the calculator to find f(x) for me when I input x, but I then get a pencil and draw a dot on actual paper. I wish people would learn how to do that.

Comment: @WillJagy Similar aesthetics but functions are geared toward financial calculations.

Comment: By that logic everything that's considered a calculation would be a substitution. So, why do they even have the word "calculation". It doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: It's very sad that these five people @Will Jagy, vadim123, Shailesh, Joey Zou, and Claude Leibovici have closed this question. They think that only the 99th explanation of Lagrange multipliers, or the number of ways to draw seven blue balls from an urn should be treated on this site.

Comment: It's very sad that these five people Will Jagy, vadim123, Shailesh, Joey Zou, and @ClaudeLeibovici have closed this question. They think that only the 99th explanation of Lagrange multipliers, or the number of ways to draw seven blue balls from an urn should be treated on this site.

Comment: I agree with Noah and Christian: the question may seem provocative but it is definitely in scope for MSE. I'm sure WIll's comments amount to something better than: "I love my calculator like I love my dog. So if you insult my calculator, you insult my dog. Insulting dogs is not in scope for MSE, so this question should be closed!", but that's the impression I get at first glance. The question deserves a better response.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to assume that we don't care about the *presentation* of a number. In fact, it's quite the opposite: we care a lot about how a number is presented, and having a tool to switch between various presentations (this is a bit more general than a calculator, on the face of it) or at least to switch from many presentations to one standard kind of presentation (this is what a calculator really does) is extremely useful.

Note, for example, that different notations make different questions easier or harder. For instance, consider $$208403=13\cdot 17\cdot 23\cdot 41.$$ We have *decimal notation* on the left, and *prime factorization* on the right. The latter notation is great for answer questions like "Is ---- divisible by $29$?", while the former is much better for comparing two quantities (e.g. which is larger: $13\cdot 17\cdot 23\cdot 41$ or $11\cdot 19 \cdot 29 \cdot 37$?), not to mention adding them (try finding the prime factorization of the sum of two numbers whose prime factorizations you know already - it's annoyingly hard!). Which one is more important? Well, as a matter of historical development we seem to have agreed, as a society, that decimal notation is the most expedient (or at least, sufficiently expedient that picking it as the "standard" presentation is a good idea).

*There's also the issue of* generalizing *presentations - e.g. decimal notation extends in a natural way to all reals, while prime factorization really doesn't. But that's another more complicated can of worms. Let's just say that even when we lay aside the difficulty of answering specific questions, there are serious* mathematical *differences between different kinds of presentations of numbers.*

There are various abstractions of the idea of "standard presentation" of a number - see the concept of **normal form** in abstract or universal algebra (or even computability theory!), and also very tangentially **term models** in mathematical logic.

---

By the way, a similar thing is going on when we solve equations: the statements "$17x+3=12$" and "$x={9\over 17}$" mean the same thing, so in some sense are the same equation; but clearly they're presented in different ways.